# Can't fetch data from MySQL (php) (Re-edited)

Tags: php, mysql

I have realized why i can't actually access userdata (after i am logged) old way to find the username is `$_SESSION['username'];` (assuming there is a row as 'username' in MySQL database)

So as i have a test account as "good25" (reason to choose numbers was to see if Alphanumeric inputs works fine.. its just checkup by me.. nevermind)

Problem :
assuming, i have rows in a table as 'username' and all of his information.. such as 'password', 'email', 'joindate', 'type' ...

On net i found out how to snatch out username from Session
`<?php session_start(); $_SESSION('username'); ?>`

successful!!

i had an idea to check if session is actually registering or no?? 
after a log on start.php i used this code
`if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { print_r($_SESSION['username']); }`

the result was "1" (while i logged in using this username "good25")
any suggestions?

> index.php (lets say, index.php just holds registration + Login form + registration script.. in login form, action='condb.php')

```
<?php 
require 'condb.php';

if (isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    //FetchInputs
    $usern = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
    $repassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['repassword']);

    $usern = trim($usern);
    $email = trim($email);
    $password = trim($password);
    $repassword = trim($repassword);

    //SearchUser
    $searchusr = "SELECT username FROM $user_table WHERE username='$usern'";
    $usersearched = mysqli_query($connection, $searchusr);
    $countuser = mysqli_num_rows($usersearched);
    //SearchEmail
    $searcheml = "SELECT email FROM $user_table WHERE email='$email'";
    $emlsearched = mysqli_query($connection, $searcheml);
    $counteml = mysqli_num_rows($emlsearched);

    //RegisteringUser
    if ($countuser == 0)
    {
        if ($counteml == 0)
        {
            $ctime = time();
            $cday = date("Y-m-d",$ctime);
            $aCode = uniqid();
            $adduser = "INSERT INTO $user_table(username, email, password, realname, activationcode, verified, joindate, type, points) VALUES ('$usern','$email','$password','$name','$aCode','n','$cday','Free',$signPoints)";
            if (mysqli_query($connection, $adduser))
            {
                ?><script>alert('You have been registered');</script><?php
            }
            else {
                ?><script>alert('Couldnt Register, please contact Admin<br><?mysqli_error($connection);?>');</script><?php
            }
        } else {
            ?><script>alert('Email already exists!');</script><?php
        }
    } else {
        ?><script>alert('Username already exists!');</script><?php
    }
}
?>
```

> condb.php

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_name);
if(!$connection) {
    die ("Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['uname']);
    $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['upass']);

    //FindUser
    $finduser = "SELECT * FROM $user_table WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$upass'";
    $findinguser = mysqli_query($connection,$finduser);

    $founduser = mysqli_num_rows($findinguser);
    //ConfirmPassword
    if ($founduser > 0)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['username'] = true;
        if ($findinguser != false)
        {
            while ($fetchD = mysqli_fetch_array($findinguser, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $fetchD['username'] = $usernn;
                $fetchD['email'] = $email;
                $fetchD['userid'] = $uid;
                $fetchD['realname'] = $rlnm;
                $fetchD['points'] = $pts;
                $fetchD['type'] = $membertype ;
            }
            header("Location: start.php");
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error();
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        ?><script>alert('Wrong details, please fill in correct password and email');</script><?php
    }
}
```

I am not asking you to build a script.. just little help please? (Thank you so so so so so much, as i am a self-learner, you don't have to say everything.. just a clue is enough for me)

Comment: Do not use mysql_* things because they are removed in PHP7.

Comment: Sir i am not using PHP7 (using PHP5)

Comment: your code is bleeding security issues. if you are a newbie its about time drop the mysql_* and have a clear start with `pdo`

Comment: @Drudge is correct. Avoid mysql_* as it is deprecated. You can use PDO for database connections. What code you have in dconn.php';?

Comment: @DevZer0 Sir i don't know anything about PDO as my hosting supplies free MySQL DB so i work in that.. can you please tell me do i have to install something and create a server for PDO? or its just builtin browser function? (please explain, thank you)

Comment: Start learning PDO or MySQLi [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: @AlankarMore "dconn.php" contains my DB password, host, username
and mysql db details (E.G. $user_table = 'surf_users')

Comment: Have you include your `require.inc.php` in other pages? As you have done in `index.php`

Comment: PDO is independent from what your hosting service provides as a database. PDO is a driver to connect to databases. using PDO will provide you a single interface more or less to work with any RDMBS (with some minor changes)

Comment: @DevZer0 can you give me link of any free hosting provider with PHP + PDO support? (currently i am working with http://freewha.com)

Comment: @AlankarMore yes i set `require ("require.inc.php");` in all of my pages .. but the thing is.. once user logs in from index.php ... on other pages.. user isn't logged in.. (seems it is connected with `Global` thing.. can you explain a bit in here.. because i can't understand from web)

Comment: @monace19 userful!! thank you brother!

Comment: Good to know that :)

Comment: @monace19 please check the script again (i have updated)

Comment: still the same error?

Comment: No i have $session problem

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this code

```
<?php
    require_once 'require.inc.php';
    //session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['btn-login']))
    {
        $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $upass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['upass']);

        $search = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username, userid, password from $user_table WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$upass'");
        $match = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);
        if ($match == 1 and $match['password'] == md5($upass))
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $match['userid'];
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>alert('Password or E-mail is wrong. If you havent registered, Please Register');</script>
            <?php
        }
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) or isset($match['userid'])){
    header("Location:start.php");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
    {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $usern = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $repassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['repassword']);

        $name = trim($name);
        $usern = trim($usern);
        $email = trim($email);
        $password = trim($password);
        $repassword = trim($repassword);

        $query = "SELECT email FROM $user_table WHERE email='$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $querytwo = "SELECT username FROM $user_table WHERE username='$usern'";
        $resulttwo = mysqli_query($connection, $querytwo);
        $counttwo = mysqli_num_rows($resulttwo);


        if ($count == 0 AND $counttwo == 0) 
        {
            if ($password == $repassword) {
                if (mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO $user_table(username, email, password, realname) VALUES ('$usern','$email','$password','$name')"))
                {
                    ?>
                    <script> alert ('Successfully registered'); </script>
                    <?php
                }
            }else {
                ?>
                <script> alert ('The Password you entered, doesnt match.. Please fill in the same password'); </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else {
            ?>
            <script> alert('Username or E-mail already exist'); </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

and this is for **require.inc.php**

```
<?php
    global $username;
    //require 'dconn.php';
    session_start();

    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "test") or die(mysqli_error());


    // Check Login
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) and isset ($match['userid']))
    {
    $Selection = "SELECT * FROM $user_table WHERE username='$username'";
    $selectQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $Selection);

        if ($selectQuery != false)
        {
            while ($fetchD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQuery))
            {
                $usernn = $fetchD['username'];
                $email = $fetchD['email'];
                $uid = $fetchD['userid'];
            }
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error();
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Why we are not including `require ('dconn.php')` ?? can you please explain a bit

Comment: Browser says 

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in $_MYWEBSITE_ on line 30"

on this line below : 

`if ($count == 0 AND $counttwo == 0){`

Comment: Mr Alex i think in dconn.php is contain this code `$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "test") or die(mysqli_error());` so i commented. if you use my entirely code there is no error

Comment: Please check the post i have edited it.. see where i am making mistake?

Comment: just add `session_start();` after `<?php` in every page and you can use `$_SESSION['username']` as users who are logged in.

Comment: Sir i have username as "good25" the login is successful.. the registration is successful too

fetching user data seems impossible.. so i had an idea
`if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { print_r($_SESSION['username']); }` magically.. an idea popped in my mind.. to see if the session is giving the right username ? (because all of my script relies on $_SESSION['username']; after user is logged in) .. RESULT = 1 ?? (its actually printing "1", not username)

Answer (score 0):

@suggestion, create session after user login and authorized then for each page start session and take session which you created and perform SQL queries using that session variable.

```
for example :
$_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];
for each page:
session_start();
$user_name=$_SESSION['user_name'];
SQL query
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users where column_name='$user_name'");
```

Comment: I think i did it before.. "starting session after successful login" i had this idea too

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include dconn.php file in all files where you want to perform the mysql operation. If you have included it only in require.inc.php then you you it in all your other files.

Comment: that seems valid.. but in PHP isn't it like chain reaction?

in index.php i added `require ("require.inc.php");`
but in require.inc.php, i actually added `require ("dconn.php");`

Comment: where ever you want to have mysqli_query to be executed you have to include require.inc.php in that script. So you need this in start.php and in contact.php

Comment: if you want to use $name in all pages then store this variable in session and change your index.php top2 lines with this  `<?php  session_start(); 
require 'condb.php'; ` and then you remaining script. then in start.php and  in contact.php just after php open tag start session to access the session variable

Comment: Sir you are right... after 2 days wondering around.. i learned few things

A session is required to have your information
I set session like this "session_start();" 

from the start i knew.. if i want my script to be executed in external page.. then i would need to add my script link in external page (i was once Javascript coder.. and i know that from that.. and take CSS as an example.. if we are attaching external page)

second most..
the thing is.. please help me out on that..  i have username "good25" (as a test) and password as "good25" (CHECKED in mysql database.. they exists) 
>Continue

Comment: <Continue from previous comment

when i be like 
`if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { print_r($_SESSION['username']); }`

magically.. an idea popped in my mind.. to see if the session is giving the right username ? (because all of my script relies on $_SESSION['username']; after user is logged in) .. 

RESULT = 1 ?? (its actually printing "1", not username)

Comment: how you are setting the value of `$_SESSION['username']` ? Please pase the code.

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` Here